# Does MudBlazor Supports Localization?

Tags: localization, mudblazor

Does MudBlazor support Localization ?

Cannot find any mentioning for localization on MudBlazor.com.
if it supports Localization, can some one guide us to achieve that.

we need an example for BLAZOR Web Server project as well as Blazor WebAssembly project.

Answer (score 0):

Not all the components support it at the moment. They have the setup documented here https://mudblazor.com/features/localization#register-service